# A process has requested access to an object, but has not been granted those access rights On windows 10 Using Selenuim with Chrome Driver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape the contents of a webpage. My code works on a Windows 7 machine that has the same versions of the drivers as my Windows 10 machine.

When I run it on windows 10, it opens a selenium controlled window, but then returns `None`, instead of the scraped content.  I have checked `Xpaths`, and everything is fine. It has the same code and drivers as the working code running on the windows 7 machine.

Debug Report Shows The Following Error :

> [0803/010730.442:ERROR:process_reader_win.cc(123)] NtOpenThread: 
>      {Access Denied} A process has requested access to an object, but has 
>      not been granted those access rights. (0xc0000022)
>      [0803/010730.445:ERROR:exception_snapshot_win.cc(98)] thread ID 472 not 
>      found in process

Answer (score 0):

When setting up the gMSA (group Managed Service Account), although you didn't specify that, the error code references:

```
{Access Denied}
```

In some cases, it isn't just the user who requires rights on a given machine.  gMSA accounts are at a computer level rather than a user level.

Is it possible that the target machine is attempting to access permission on the source machine?  If that is the case, it could be for several reasons.   If you are on a domain, the source server (the one being scraped on its web content), may not allow the target server account rights and it won't matter what code is used, the server (computer) will reject the rights before it checks the user access.

If on a local domain, it may be worth checking whether there is access for that port, though not probable as most everything runs on port 443, but perhaps the web page is on 1443 or 8443 or something similar and that port is not open on the domain (or private if you are running this in a home lab).   This latter reason doesn't make sense because your web server would be open on that port, but it could be a port blocking issue as well as a block from computer to computer.

442 Error can also refer to a VPN issue where the VPN is blocking the access.

If it is a VPN error, there is a fix here:

```
https://www.vpndig.com/tutorial/fix-error-442-in-cisco-vpn
```